# How to \input the part between \begin{document} and \end{document} from another LaTeX file?

Tags: input

Sometimes I want to `\input` some LaTeX code, which belongs to a standalone LaTeX file.

I would like to input the part between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, while skipping the other part.

Comment: With “standalone” LaTeX file, do you mean that you are using the `standalone` document class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is exactly the purpose of the [docmute](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/docmute.html) package.  Another one with more options is the package and document class [standalone](http://mirror.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/standalone.html).

Comment: For this you only need to load the `standalone` package and then simply `\input` the other file. The `standalone` class is not required, but useful for the other file if it is a diagram or similar which you want to compile on its own with minimal borders.